# Destructure a solid color into overlayed colors with transparency

Tags: c#, colors, computer-vision, alpha

I am working on an application, in which I export an image with different shapes (rectangles, circles, polygons and etc). Each shape has its own unique color. Currently, the colors are solid and have no transparency and this gives me a strong limitation: If a shape is placed over another shape, the shape below the first one is lost. This is really bad, because, sometimes there is a very large object, that stays on top and hides more than 100 smaller elements below it. Example image:

[image]

The used colors are solid red(255, 0, 0), green(0, 255, 0) and blue(0, 0, 255)

I have an idea how to fix that, but I don't know if it is possible and this is why I am asking here. I want to try to set transparency to each shape (e.g. 0.3/1) and by doing this, I will be able to see all shapes. Example image:

[image]

What I want to do, is to find a way to destructure all colors, that compose a particular pixel. For example - in the middle of the picture where all three shapes are overlayed, the color that is generated is a solid one with RGB(163, 124, 141). I want to be able to extract the following colors: RGBA(255,0,0,0.3), RGBA(0,255,0,0.3), RGBA(0,0,255,0.3). Let's say that the Alpha component will be a constant and set to 0.3 if that helps.

As I said, I don't know if this is possible, but any suggestion will be highly appreciated. The programming languages that I use in my project are C#, Go and JavaScript, but any suggestion in another language will be appreciated as well.

Comment: While color/alpha blending can be quite complex (to wit: look at the photoshop modes!) your case will be solvable for  some cases : picking n pixels with different  colors results in n equations and these can be solved if only n shapes are used and all combinations/overlapping are present. If two shapes are identical their colors cannnot be reconstructed.

Comment: I think I understand, but now I have another question. Is it then possible to check if the result color could be achieved by another given. For example I have a final color RGB(100,100,100), can I iterate over all color combinations (rgba(0,0,1,0.3), rgba(0,0,2,0.3), etc.) and check if it is possible to be part of the final solid color?

Comment: Lets simplify the issue by looking athe channels separately. If we assume a simplistic blending mode that simply adds all channels Even the 1st color can be anything as the two others will be able to get to 100. If the target values 255 otoh only one solution is possible. ((Aside: Do note that the GDI color blending is quite crappy and doesn't work that way and all those ideas will not be be possible to achieve with simple gdi drawing code!)

Comment: I see. So probably this approach would not be possible as I thought. Do you have then any other idea, on how can I then identify multiple shapes overlayed over each other? (this must happen when a user clicks anywhere in the image and I have to ask him which of all overlayed shapes he wants to select)

Comment: Where do the shapes come from? Do you draw themß Then you can easily remeber them and test which were hit..

Comment: Well, I generate them, and I also know every unique color that has been used. But when a bigger object is placed over a smaller one, I lose the smaller one and I only have the metadata for it in the database, but the user is not able access it.

Comment: Well, keep the coodinates/graphicspaths and test which contain the mouse point..

Comment: The problem is that the shape could have "holes" inside it and also could be large and complex shapes and saving such information would bring me performance/memory issues.

Comment: How exactly do you then draw them? - What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211875/discussion-between-enchew-and-taw).